# Javascript link to bookmarklet not working

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I've made a simple bookmarklet, to aid with the reading of Daring Fireball.

http://saltcod.github.com/Snowball/

My issue is that the `Drag Me Up, Scottie!` link doesn't work when you drag it up. If you manually create the bookmark with the same code (https://raw.github.com/saltcod/Snowball/master/snowball.js) it will work, but it won't work if you try and drag it up.

The link is breaking the block of Javascript somehow.  Anyone got any ideas as to what I might do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You messed up the quotation marks; your page is NOT valid HTML.

Inside a link, you cannot use `"`, but either use `'` or encode the quotation marks.

Did you not notice that your javascript link was truncated at the first `"`?